# modernCV seems to forbid any hyphenation. How can I switch that off?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation, moderncv

I'm writing a document with the help of the `modernCV` class, using (a modification of) the `casual` style. It looks like this class is penalizing hyphenation pretty severely. Why is that so? I can't find something like `\hyphenpenalty=` set to a very high value in `moderncv.cls`.

How can I allow hyphenation in the cover letter?

Comment: `moderncvstylecasual.sty` has `\raggedright` a couple of places, which will turn off hyphenation I believe. Do those influence the text you were thinking of?

Comment: [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) sets the letter in `\raggedright` justification. If you want to have it justified, add the [`ragged2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package to your preamble and issue `\justifying` where you want to allow hyphenation. Of course, you can also patch `\makelettertitle` to remove `\raggedright`.

Comment: As an addendum to @Werner's post: `ragged2e` also provides `\Raggedright` which sets the text ragged right but still allows hyphenation. (Should you want that.)

Comment: `ragged2e`s `/RaggedRight` does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easiest to just add the [`ragged2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) to your preamble

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e
```

and use

```
\makelettertitle\justifying
```

[image]

You could use any of the other justification styles as well.

Comment: I've settled with `/RaggedRight`. Also, the part in your letter after the lorem ipsum angers and amuses me.